# OpenCV with Glassfish webapplication

Tags: java, jsf, opencv, glassfish, glassfish-4

I'm trying to develop a Java webapplication with Glassfish using JSF and OpenCV. I wrote some code which works fine on Java desktop application. However, when I try to implement it on Glassfish app it shows me an error `UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(IIIDDDD)J`, when I use `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)` before I get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library already loaded in another classloader`.

I tried putting loading code into singleton - still this same situation. Tried to load singleton in different application and call it by `Class.forName()` - dll loaded but the application still doesn't work and the first error appears `UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(IIIDDDD)J`.

I tested OpenCV 2.4.10, 2.4.11 and 3.0 versions under Glassfish 4 and Glassfish 4.1 servers. I'm working on Windows and using Netbeans.

Please help me because I got stuck and have no idea what else I can do with it.
Thank you in advance.